# Order and Grouping of Imports in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I know PEP8 and used Google. PEP8 says:

> Imports should be grouped in the following order:
>
> - standard library imports
> - related third party imports
> - local application/library specific imports
>
> You should put a blank line between each group of imports.

Using Google is hard when search terms are something like "python imports pep8 good practice", because you end up with results that are answers to absolute newbie questions...

How should the following lines, that are not made up, but from a real world script, look like? To me they look completely wrong, but, well, I think PEP8 is not really complete here...

```
from __future__ import division

import math  # Python Standard Library 
import sys

import clr  #  .NET Common Language Runtime
from System import Array, Double  # .NET libraries
import System.Collections.Generic

path2K2 = "C:\\YourModuleFolder"
if path2K2 not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path2K2)  # needs to be set before next line

# needs to be called before 'import KangarooSolver as ks'
clr.AddReferenceToFile("KangarooSolver.dll")

import Grasshopper as gh  # plug-in for Rhino
import KangarooSolver as ks  # plug-in for Grasshopper
import Rhino as rc  # main program
```

Comment: The only thing that I can see is that I'd put the `from` imports later, or do `import System.Array as Array` etc.